# ImplicitRegion fails on apparently simple case

Tags: regions

Consider the shaded region bounded by $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $\tan x$:

[image]

We can define this as an `ImplicitRegion` by:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = 
 ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1) \[And] (y < Cos[x]) \[And] 
     (y < Tan[x]) \[And] (y > Sin[x]),
  {x, y}]
```

However, `RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR]]` fails to yield a figure after 15 minutes (v 11.3, MacOS).

However if I'm "smart" and put the bounds as $0<x< \pi/4$ I *do* get a plot.

Moreover, its area,

```
RegionMeasure[\[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

does not give an analytic solution (even after `RootReduce`, `Simplify`, etc.) even though [an analytic form exists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abHeMmxdNQU).

(One *can* get a numerical value through `N@RegionMeasure[\[ScriptCapitalR]]`, but I seek the *analytic* solution.)

I've tried various forms based on `RegionIntersection[]` and such, without success.

Of course I can use traditional calculus through `Integrate` and finding intersection points, but I'd like to compute the area more directly.

How can I 1) plot the region and (more importantly) 2) compute the analytic area?

Comment: for (1) try `RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion@\[ScriptCapitalR]]`?

Comment: and for (2) `FullSimplify[ToRadicals@RegionMeasure@\[ScriptCapitalR]]` gives `1/2 (-1 + 2 Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[5] + ArcCsch[2])` (version 11.3 windows)

Comment: Yep.  (1) *AND* (2) work.  Post and I'll accept.  Thanks (again).

Comment: 12.3.1 work fine. Or using `Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]]`

Comment: How is that region finite? given that the region as described repeats itself in every interval `{2 n  Pi, (2 n+1/4) Pi}` for all `n` Integer? Also, why does Mathematica considers only the region for `n=0`?

Comment: Because $0 < x< 1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1.** Process `ℛ` with `DiscretizeRegion` before feeding it to `RegionPlot`:

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[(0 < x < 1) ∧ (y < Cos[x]) ∧ (y < Tan[x]) ∧ (y > Sin[x]), {x, y}]

RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion @ ℛ]
```

[image]

**2.** A composition of `FullSimplify` and  `RegionMeasure` gives an exact result:

```
FullSimplify @ RegionMeasure @ ℛ
```

> ```
>   1/2 (-1 + 2 Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[5] + ArcCsch[2])
> ```